# rethinkdb join: Cannot reduce over an empty stream

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-javascript

I have two simple tables:

**Users Table:**

```
{
"activated": true ,
"created": Wed Jun 22 2016 15:22:32 GMT+00:00 ,
"email": email@email.com, »
"id":  "5071f620-576a-49c0-ae84-e9f32db2a034" ,
"roles": [
"Admin"
] ,
"sso":  "123456789"
}
```

**Roles Table:**

```
{
"id":  "f62b1d29-84d1-4bad-a359-dacb8678f607" ,
"permissions": [
"add" ,
"delete"
] ,
"role":  "Admin"
}
```

I am running a query to get the permissions of a given user. I am doing the following:

```
r.db('content').table("users").merge(function(user){
  return r.object(
    'permissions', user('roles').eqJoin(function(id){
      return id
    }, r.db('content').table('roles')).zip()('permissions')
    .reduce(function(left, right){
      return left.merge(right)
    })
    )      
});
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Server error:

e: Cannot reduce over an empty stream
```

What am I doing wrong and why? My desired output will give me a user with their permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's trying to look for a document in the `roles` table with an `id` of `Admin` rather than a `role` of `Admin`.  Assuming you have an index on `role` in the `roles` table (if you don't you can add one by writing `r.db('content').table('roles').indexCreate('role')`), you should be able to fix it by adding `{index: 'role'}` to the `eqJoin` call.

```
r.db('content').table("users").merge(function(user){
  return r.object(
    'permissions', user('roles').eqJoin(function(id){
      return id
    }, r.db('content').table('roles'), {index: 'role'}).zip()('permissions')
    .reduce(function(left, right){
      return left.merge(right)
    })
    )      
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example, mainly, could you show what you mean by "adding `{index: 'role'}` to the eqJoin call"

Comment: Edited the original answer.  You literally just put `{index: 'role'}` at the end of the `eqJoin` call.